# How to give the user an ability to create a new chat room in socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, chat

How to give the user an ability to create a new chat room in `socket.io`?

I couldn't find any documentation about how to do this.

Comment: Have you read this? [http://socket.io/get-started/chat/](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/)

Comment: Sure. I know how to create rooms myself with the code but have no idea how to give user the permission to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Demo logic :
User emit a `createRoom` event

Server check role if have permission , create a new room , emit `createdRoom` event to user

User receive this event and save this room info